# Skip nan annotation in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How is it possible to drop the nans in the heatmap annotation while keeping the colorcoding?

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =  np.random.random((15,15))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
annot_df = df.applymap(lambda f: f'{f:.1f}')
annot_df=annot_df.to_numpy()
np.put(annot_df,np.random.choice(annot_df.size, 21, replace=False),np.nan)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(
    df,
    cbar=False,
    annot=annot_df,
    fmt="",
    annot_kws={"size": 10, "va": "center_baseline"},
    cmap="magma",
    vmin=-1,
    vmax=1,
    square=True)
plt.show()
```

[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuKPn.png)

Masking only also removes the colorcoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mask argument for [sns.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) is for situations where you want to mask data by *value* and not apply heatmap coloring on the masked cells. If you want to just drop the annotation altogether but keep the coloring, you can use empty string in place of `np.nan` in your annotations.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((15, 15))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
annot_df = df.applymap(lambda f: f"{f:.1f}")
annot_df = annot_df.to_numpy()
np.put(annot_df, np.random.choice(annot_df.size, 21, replace=False), "") # The only change here
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.heatmap(
    df,
    cbar=False,
    annot=annot_df,
    fmt="",
    annot_kws={"size": 10, "va": "center_baseline"},
    cmap="magma",
    vmin=-1,
    vmax=1,
    square=True,
)
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with nans replaced with empty strings]

Answer (score 0):

You can just go with

`np.put(annot_df,np.random.choice(annot_df.size, 21, replace=False), "")`